# "Your mom has an outie" = "son of a bitch" in English?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, slang, spoken-language, internet-slang

This might seem ridiculous, but I've now encountered "Your mom has an outie" twice in anime, and both times, it's been translated as "son of a bitch." I just want to know if there's something to this, or if it's one hell of a coincidence @.@.

In particular, in "Bokura ga Ita", the angry FeMC says to the male love interest "お前の母ちゃんは出べそ", which is translated as "Son of a bitch!" in the subtitles. I thought this was just the translators being overly zealous, but then...
[image: bokura ga ita]

in Masamune-kun no Revenge, an angry FeMC asks the male love interest to translate "お前の母ちゃん出べそ" into English, and the male love interest literally says in engrish "Son of a bitch" (i.e. "サノバビッチ"). The context for this is FeMC is miffed that male-love-interest-kun could be so smart, so accosts him with a series of questions.
[image: Masamune-kun no Revenge]

Note that the Masamune-kun instance is literally firsthand (not just english translation shenanigans), which leads me to believe there's something to this @.@.

Comment: Very much unsure, so posting as a comment rather than an answer. :) I suspect that calling someone a 出【で】べそ ("outie") might be equivalent to calling them a bumpkin—an old-school protruding navel would suggest a lack of proper healthcare when the person was born. So saying that someone's mom has an outie is saying that they're the child of a bumpkin / rustic person, by extension, a hick or yokel. If so, this doesn't align very well with the SOB expression as used in English. In medical contexts, 出べそ apparently refers to an umbilical hernia, but I don't see a connection to the slang sense here.

Comment: FYI: [What are the funniest swear words in foreign languages that don't have any English equivalent?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-funniest-swear-words-in-foreign-languages-that-dont-have-any-English-equivalent)

Answer (score 3):

From a pragmatic point of view,  お前の母ちゃんでべそ is a widely recognized way of insulting but not really used in reality (I don't think I've ever heard it used in my childhood). Anyway, the meaning does not really play a role if it is ever used. If I can assume English speakers do not REALLY imply the literal meaning of *son of a bitch* or *motherfxxker*, お前の母ちゃんでべそ is close (perhaps) except that English versions are used more often.

Etymologically, お前の母ちゃんでべそ seems even more close to those English versions. According to [this](https://www.poc39.com/archives/1278),

- Theory 1: でべそ is an euphemism for sexual organ so that the phrase implies the speaker has seen the other's mother naked, implying she is a bitch. This makes the phrase closer to *son of a bitch*.
- Theory 2: でべそ suggests the tie with the mother, implying an incestuous relationship. This make the phrase closer to *motherfxxker*. (see [this](https://news.livedoor.com/article/detail/18550958/) also)

I have no idea of the legitimacy of these theories, but they are not commonly known anyway.